# Переход с главной страницы на страницу авторизации в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, авторизация, route

Я смотрю [Авторизация в Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Prau254LCqk&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t8pnG4ubQemoqnTwf0VFEtU&index=33). На этом видео с 2:09-2:15 при обновлении страницы http://127.0.0.1:8000/ возникает страница http://127.0.0.1:8000/login. За счет чего конкретно это происходит?

Comment: за счёт шлюзов или политик https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/authorization#introduction

Comment: Добавите скриншот вашего кода, web.php

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян сейчас не могу, приведу web.php позднее.

Comment: У него в видюшке, на пути (точнее в контроллере) стоит `->middleware('auth')`